# Php CURL to work with cookies and session

Tags: php, curl

```
function get_data($url,$proxy=Null){
        $agents = array(
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1',
            'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1.9) Gecko/20100508 SeaMonkey/2.0.4',
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; en-US)',
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7; da-dk) AppleWebKit/533.21.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.5 Safari/533.21.1'

        );    
            $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
            $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
            $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
            $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
            $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
            $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
            $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
            $header[] = "Pragma: ";   

$curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$agents[array_rand($agents)]);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://google.com/");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); ///** Follow Redirect
        $html1 = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $html1;
}
```

Above is my function and i am trying to get a page from proxy site

```
echo get_data('http://www.hostfast.info/browse.php?u=lZpnCp2dHRM0%2BnBp1Ljfmr8I%2BA%3D%3D&b=5');
```

But this is not working ....its giving me home page of that site  and if i am trying new search its also not working... i am new to CURL ... but i think there is some thing to do with cookies ... how can i fix this

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
define('POSTURL', 'http://hostfast.info/includes/process.php?action=update');
 define('POSTVARS', 'u=google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=love');  // POST VARIABLES TO BE SENT

 $ch = curl_init(POSTURL);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST      ,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS    ,POSTVARS);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER      ,0);  // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  ,1);  // RETURN THE CONTENTS OF THE CALL
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "yourcookiefile.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "yourcookiefile.txt");
 $Rec_Data = curl_exec($ch);


 curl_close($ch);


echo $Rec_Data;
```

This works .. ;)

Answer (score 1):

To save cookie in cURL with PHP:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "yourcookiefile.txt");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "yourcookiefile.txt");
```

Comment: Does your link work in browser ( For me it returns home page )? You can test any curl without php for example in Chrome use Postman extension to simulate post/get requests with headers and fields then you will get same. Also in firefox Poster plugin but this is worse.

Comment: this link only work only one browser as it store cookies or session in that browser if you copy and past it in another browser it will not work .. :(

Comment: session token can be stored in server, you should with curl emulate all process from login to search.